# In the Wan oracle curse description, what does "'inflict' spell" mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, oracle

From the Pathfinder SRD's description of the third-party [Wan oracle curse](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#Wan_3PP) from *Oracle’s Curse* (emphasis mine):

> You are pale, sickly, and languorous, with one foot in death’s door.
>
> #### Effect
>
> You have the fatigued condition, but are immune to the exhausted
> condition.
>
> **At 5th level, you learn the “inflict” spell of any level spell you can
> cast.**
>
> At 10th level, add *ray of exhaustion* to your spells known.
>
> At 15th level, add *waves of exhaustion* to your spells known.

I was skimming through the oracle curses list on the Pathfinder SRD and found the curse quoted above. I'm confused by the wording.

Is there a spell called "inflict" that I'm not aware of, or is it a method of delivery? Maybe it's referring to [*inflict light wounds*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/inflict-light-wounds/) and [*inflict moderate wounds*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/inflict-moderate-wounds/). That's my best guess, but I'm likely wrong on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not wrong. "Inflict spells" implies any spell with the word "Inflict" in its name, generally refers to the following line of spells:

1. Inflict Light Wounds
2. Inflict Moderate Wounds
3. Inflict Serious Wounds
4. Inflict Critical Wounds
5. Inflict Light Wounds, Mass
6. Inflict Moderate Wounds, Mass
7. Inflict Serious Wounds, Mass
8. Inflict Critical Wounds, Mass

However, there are two others that also qualify:

9. [Inflict Pain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/inflict-pain/)
10. Inflict Pain, Mass

If the author of the curse didn't intend for you to be able to take those, he should have specified. RAW, you can.

Comment: That sounds like a useless feature since you already get all inflict spells from the oracles spellcasting feature should you choose to go that route.

Comment: I was thinking that, but that's not what the OP was asking about. It's a bit more useful than that if you choose to go Cure spells normally, but even then there's much stronger abilities than getting a single sub-par damage or healing spell.

Comment: I'm the op lol thanks for the clarification.

Comment: ...well I derped there. XD Yeah, the curse is definitely on the weaker side. If it said "every" not "any", it would still be on the weaker side since the inflict spells are still below-par as damaging spells.

Comment: I do think the intent is "every" level; 3pp content generally uses slightly more lax wording and that seems to be the intent (otherwise they would have said Inflict Light, Inflict Moderate, (and/or) Inflict Serious Wounds)

Comment: That may be the intent, sure, but RAW that's not the case. I'd consider it a reasonable house-rule, though a house-rule of a third-party curse makes me a little nervous no matter how you spin it.